# Running a query on property change

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

I am quite new to svelte and haven't quite gotten my head around bindings and updates.

My component is supposed to query the server everytime the `jobId` property changes, but I can't seem to figure out how.

```
<script>
    import StatusItem from './StatusItem.svelte';
    import { getClient, query } from 'svelte-apollo';
    import { client, JOBDETAIL } from '../data';

    export let jobId;

    let steps = query(client, { query: JOBDETAIL, variables: { id: jobId } })
</script>

<div class="steps">
    {jobId}
        {#await $steps}
            Loading...
        {:then result}
            {#each result.data.history[0].details as step}
                <StatusItem title={step.step} subtitle={step.time} status={step.status}/>
            {/each}
        {/await}
</div>
```

The issue is that it of course doesn't call the `query` function when `jobId` changes, and I can see why it doesn't. But I can't figure out how to solve it. I tried using `beforeUpdate` but that didn't seem right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using [reactive statements](https://svelte.dev/docs#3_$_marks_a_statement_as_reactive)

```html
<script>
    import StatusItem from './StatusItem.svelte';
    import { getClient, query } from 'svelte-apollo';
    import { client, JOBDETAIL } from '../data';

    export let jobId;

    $: steps = query(client, { query: JOBDETAIL, variables: { id: jobId } })
</script>

<div class="steps">
    {jobId}
        {#await $steps}
            Loading...
        {:then result}
            {#each result.data.history[0].details as step}
                <StatusItem title={step.step} subtitle={step.time} status={step.status}/>
            {/each}
        {/await}
</div>
```